# java servlets response - stay on same page

Tags: java, html, flash, servlets

Hi I call Java servlet using flash navigateToURL method.

In some cases I want the servlet to tell the browser client to stay on the same page - How can I achieve that? If the response is empty than the page becomes blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong method to access java servlets. If you need to keep the same page open, navigateToURL is not what you should use. nagivateToURL method is as per the documentation:

**Opens or replaces a window in the application that contains the Flash Player container (usually a browser). In Adobe AIR, the function opens a URL in the default system web browser**

You can use

1. Flash Remoting APIs for calling servlets
2. [HttpService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html)
3. [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html1.) method.

Check the links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `navigateToURL` instructs the browser to open another URL. The content is fetched after the browser navigation changes.

You should make an HTTP request within the flex app. This can be done like this:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.param1 = "param1";
vars.param2 = "param2";
req.data = vars;
req.url = "/targetUrl";

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, pageLoadComplete);
loader.load(req);
```

And then in the `pageLoadComplete(event:Event)` method:

```
var result:String = URLLoader(event.currentTarget).data.toString();
```

It is advisable to make such a call to a URL that returns simply `true` or `false`, depending on whether you will have to redirect or not.

Comment: The problem is that the servlet should instruct the browser to open "save dialog" to save a file - in case everything is OK. In this case, navigateToURL is good for me. in case of error, i have a problem

Comment: @Erik , you cannot instruct the browser to open "save dialog". If you send the file with proper mime, it will open the save dialog. In case of any error, change the mime to text and return an error message.

Comment: thats exactly what i do - i set the mimetype of the file so the browser opens the save dialog. Still, i have to use navigateToURL, no?

Comment: @Erik, no try using URLRequest and FileReference... it should help you